# Divergence, curl, and gradient of a complex function

Tags: cauchy-integral-formula

From an answer here I got 
Green's theorem for functions in the complex plane

$$
\oint f(z) \, dz = 
i \iint \left( \nabla f \right) \, dx \, dy = 
i \iint \left( 1 {\partial f \over \partial x} + 
i {\partial f \over \partial y} \right) \, dx \, dy
$$

Which leads to the well known Cauchy's integral theorem

$$
\oint f(z) \, dz = 
\iint 
\left( \frac{- \partial f_x}{\partial y} + \frac{- \partial f_y}{\partial x}  \right)+
i \left( \frac{\partial f_x}{\partial x} + \frac{- \partial f_y}{\partial y} \right)  \, dx \, dy
$$
From which I then get
$$
\oint f(z) \, dz = 
\iint \left( 
\nabla \times f +
i \nabla \cdot f 
\right) \, dx \, dy 
$$
 I'm hoping someone here can tell me whether I'm on the right track or not.

Keep in mind that
$$\nabla =  1 {\partial \over \partial x} + 
i {\partial \over \partial y}$$

Comment: You can use `\mathbf{f}` $\mathbf{f}$ or `\vec{f}` $\vec{f}$ for vectors.

Comment: There are no vectors. The complex numbers are being treated as though they were vectors though

Comment: Bro, it’s just a MathJax tip; no need to get defensive about it. And by the way, I would strongly contend that divergence and curl only make sense as operators on vectors and that vectors within the complex plane are very much actual vectors.

Comment: I didn't get defensive about it. Why would you think I was getting defensive about it?

Comment: Try it with some functions, like $f(z)=z$.

Comment: I calculated curl of f(z)=-iz and got -2 for all z

Comment: Does it satisfy your formula?

Comment: It seems too based on this https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/Complex_curl.png

Comment: Well it took me 3 days to do what should have taken 30 minutes but I finally did it. Its all based on http://www.solitaryroad.com/c606.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a physicist, but I think that gradient, curl, and divergence are strictly for a real $d$-dimensional environment, in particular for $d=2$ and $d=3$. I have never met your strange complex definition of $\nabla$.

On the other hand it is of course possible to prove the Cauchy integral formula using Green's theorem in the form
$$\int_{\partial \Omega}\bigl(P(x,y)\>dx+Q(x,y)\>dy\bigr)=\int_\Omega(Q_x-P_y)\>{\rm d}(x,y)\ .\tag{1}$$
Write your analytic $f$ in the form $f=u+ iv$ as well as $dz$ in the form $dz=dx+i dy$. Then by definition of complex line integrals you have
$$\int_{\partial\Omega}f(z)\>dz=\int_{\partial\Omega}(u\>dx-v\>dy)+i\int_{\partial\Omega}(v\>dx+ u\>dy)\ ,$$
to which you can apply $(1)$ separately. Finally the CR equations will come to your rescue.